# Qlikview Export Screenshot To Email

Tags: email, export, snapshot, qlikview

I'm trying to write a script for a button in my app named Export. The main idea is that the button will take a screenshot of the current active sheet, and attach it to an email in outlook. Here is what it's supposed to do:

1. Open up Outlook (done)
2. Attach the image in the email (done)

However, my script only works on my local machine. It will not work once I deploy it onto the Qlikview server. I suspect is is because I save it into my local C drive. How do I get it to work once I deploy it on the server?

Here's my code:

```
sub sendMail()  
    Set appOutlook = CreateObject("outlook.application")
        'create a new message
        Set Message = appOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        With Message
            .Subject = "Testing Daily Report"

            .HTMLBody = "<span LANG=EN>" _
                & "<p class=style2><span LANG=EN><font FACE=Calibri SIZE=3>" _
                & "Hello,<br ><br >The weekly dashboard is now available. " _
                & "<br>The main overview is attached below:<BR>"

            'first we create the image as a JPG file
            ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.ExportBitmapToFile "C:\Snapshot.PNG"   
            'we attached the embedded image with a Position at 0 (makes the attachment hidden)
            TempFilePath = "C:\"
            .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & "Snapshot.PNG", olByValue, 0

            'Then we add an html <img src=''> link to this image
            'Note than you can customize width and height - not mandatory

            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "<img src='cid:Snapshot.PNG'" & "width='1200' height='600'><br>"

            .To = " "


            .Display

        End With
end sub
```

Comment: if you want it to work on the client computer, they will have to use Internet explorer with the qlikview plugin installed....

Comment: I tried what you did, looks like something to do with permissions and server. I'll have a look tomorrow as I'm also interested in it.

Comment: @husker cool let me know if you find something. I tried changing the directory in the line "ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.ExportBitmapToFile "C:\Snapshot.PNG" and "TempFilePath = C:\" to the QMC shared folder. The latter makes the script not work at all, and I'm not sure if the former is working as it should.

Comment: @NabeelZulkifli I'm having the problem even with the simple alert, which version are you using? I'm using version 11

Comment: @husker 11 as well. SR13. What happens for me when I click it is a notification will pop up in Outlook, saying a program wants to access email info. Just click on allow, and it'll automatically open a new message with the image attached in the body.

Comment: @NabeelZulkifli is that when you run it locally? because locally it works for me, the problem is when I placed in the server and I run remotely, nothing happens.

Comment: @husker yeah locally. well that's the problem I can't get it working in the server either.

Comment: @NabeelZulkifli I've being looking into this doc https://qlikviewtips.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/is-possible-make-macros-that-run-server-side/ so far I can create the TXT but I'm failing in creating the png

Comment: @husker well that's not good. I still can't get it to work either.

Comment: @husker any breakthroughs by any chance?